# How to add a list after an existing list but not expand it?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

Hi~ It seems like a simple question, but I failed to find it being asked and answered.

I have a dictionary `data_dict` like `{'keyId':['1','2','3']}`.
Now I'd like to add some new lists (namely `['a','b','c']`) and make it like `{'keyId':['1','2','3'],['a','b','c']}`, so I do it as

```
for new_list in lists:
    data_dict[keyId].append(new_list)
```

But it turned out to be like `{'keyId':['1','2','3',['a','b','c']]}`.

Comment: `{'keyId':['1','2','3'],['a','b','c']}` is not a python valid syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{'keyId':['1','2','3'],['a','b','c']}` is not a valid Python data structure.

What you could do is implement `keyId` as a list of lists:

```py
data_dict = {'keyId':[['1','2','3']]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lists are unhashable – you can't use them in dictionaries because they are mutable. You can use a tuple of the lists instead.

```
data_dict = {'keyId':(['1','2','3'])}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a unique key, something hashable, and as a value, a list, and then you can populate it:

```
lists = [[2,3,4], [5,4,5], "abd"]

data_dict = {}

keyId = "hashable_obj"

data_dict[keyId] = []

for new_list in lists:
    data_dict[keyId].append(new_list)

print(data_dict)
```

output:

```
{'hashable_obj': [[2, 3, 4], [5, 4, 5], 'abd']}
```

Answer (score 0):

The important characteristics of Python lists are as follows:

- Lists are ordered.
- Lists can contain any arbitrary objects.
- List elements can be accessed by index.
- Lists can be nested to arbitrary depth.
- Lists are mutable.
- Lists are dynamic.

List item so I would suggest with list based approach. Here is the [source link](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/) to understand between list and tuple.

```
my_list = [[1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
my_dict = {}
my_dict['KeyId'] = []
for new_list in my_list:
    my_dict['KeyId'].append(new_list)
```

Output

```
{'KeyId': [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]}
```